# session_start(): Failed to decode session object

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I am sometime experiencing the following issue with CodeIgniter:

> ERROR - 2019-03-05 19:57:26 --> Severity: Warning --> session_start():
>   Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed
>   /system/libraries/Session/Session.php 143

This error appears in my server log and is impossible to artificialy replicate.

I already read the following SO questions:

- [PHP: session | Failed to decode session object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858473/php-session-failed-to-decode-session-object)
- [PHP session_start() fails to create session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987459/php-session-start-fails-to-create-session)
- [Session destroyed out of nowhere in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944892/session-destroyed-out-of-nowhere-in-php)

I also asked on the CodeIgniter forum, but I didn't have any answer.

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-72960.html

Here are my session configuration (in `application/config/config.php`)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Any ideas what could be the roots of that problem and/or where to start ?

Comment: Are sessions getting stored in the DB or the standard way? You should be able to set this in the Codigniter config file.

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944892/session-destroyed-out-of-nowhere-in-php

Comment: Yes, I already read this question, but answers didn't help me so much. For the DB storage, I guess the session is stored in a file ( $config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In application/config/config.php, set this value:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this error when using the database option to store session information. When using this option, CodeIgniter stores session data in a table called ci_sessions, specifically in the 'data' column. By default, CodeIgniter creates this column as a blob datatype which has a maximum data size of 65,535 bytes. My application was exceeding that size and throwing the error. To remedy the issue, I changed the datatype to mediumblob which has a maximum size of 16,777,215 bytes. Afterwards, my application no longer generated the error and worked as expected.

Comment: I was wondering how come the session is destroying for my users. This one fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with this setting

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

When using the "files" driver, which you are, as determined by the following

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

`$config['sess_save_path']` must be set to the **absolute path** where the session files will be stored. e.g.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/var/www/project/sessions/';
```

When set to NULL all kinds of weird and unpredictable things happen. The folder must also have appropriate ownership and permissions.